# Custom numeric format string based on number sign

Tags: c#, formatting, string-formatting

I am trying to format a decimal (as a percentage without the % sign), displaying brackets () around negative numbers and displaying positive numbers as is.

```
var returnString = value.HasValue
            ? string.Format("{0:0.0;(0.0)}", value.Value * 100) :
            DefaultEmptyString;

return returnString;
```

My main problem is that for a numbers such as -0.000491 which in this formatting scheme is a zero it should still show the brackets as it is a negative zero.
Nonetheless, it is being lost.

I could stop using the [section separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator) and utilize an *if* statement instead but it seems like the section separator should do the trick.

Any ideas why the formatting is not done correctly ?

Comment: None of the default data types like integer or double allow for `0` to be a negative.  If you want to have a negative 0 then you have to added the negative sign to the string yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas why the formatting is not done correctly ?

Is *is* done correctly according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator):

> If the number to be formatted is negative, but becomes zero after rounding according to the format in the second section, the resulting zero is formatted according to the first section.

Since I don't see any options available that would override that default behavior, one option is to append the parentheses manually:

```
public string Format(decimal value)
{
   string s = (value*100).ToString("0.0;0.0");
   if(value < 0)
      s = "(" + s + ")";
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

"If the number to be formatted is negative, but becomes zero after rounding according to the format in the second section, then the resulting zero is formatted according to the first section."

The formatting is correct, you will need the if statement.